# Check if a number is prime using Apex

Tags: apex

I'm looking for an implementation in Apex to determine if a number is [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) or not.

Motivation: I was using testing primality as an example of the edge cases and challenges in Test driven development and realized there isn't a good reference implantation available in Apex.

Answer (score 6):

I came up with the following. It is more or less an exact translation of the [C# example from StackOverflow by Soner Gönül](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15743238/54026).

Note that it includes a boundary for the square root of the number being checked as [there is no need to check higher factors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811176/54026).

Larger primes are going to be a challenge as divisibility by all odd numbers from 3 upward will be checked up to the boundary.

```
public static boolean isPrimeNumber(integer toTest) {
    if (toTest == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException('null');
    if (toTest <= 1) return false;
    if (toTest == 2) return true;
    if (Math.mod(toTest, 2) == 0) return false;

    integer boundary = (integer)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(toTest));
          
    for (integer i = 3; i <= boundary; i += 2) {
        if (Math.mod(toTest, i) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true; 
}
```

Very basic test case for the first 25 primes. Filling in the remainder is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
@IsTest
public static void longerCheck() {
    integer[] knownPrimes = new List<integer>{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97};
        
    for(integer i = -1; i <= 100; i++) {
        boolean isIPrime = MathImplementation.isPrimeNumber(i);
        boolean shouldBePrime = knownPrimes.contains(i);
        System.assertEquals(shouldBePrime, isIPrime, 'Failed on ' + i);
    }
}
```